# Is there a way to know when nobody is broadcasting with Agora (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to make a 'broadcast' video share in Unity, where only one person 'owns' the video, they have to press a button to 'be broadcaster' which shuts out all other users until the broadcaster stops or leaves. 
What I need to know is, when the broadcaster stops or leaves, what's the best way to know that 'nobody is broadcasting'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the question!
I'm fairly certain that the Agora SDK isn't able to explicitly tell how many users are in a channel. That functionality has to be handled inside a Unity script, instead of directly asking the Agora SDK.

I'd recommend using the [OnUserOfflineHandler()](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/unity/namespaceagora__gaming__rtc.html#a98bfb4310e947f95dbc43c071c2f8ccf), and checking to see if the 'special broadcasters' UID is equal to that of the user who just left, if so, fire some custom event you've created to alert interested subscribers.